# How do I get ls --color=auto to work on Mac OS X?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, ls

I'm trying to move my bash configuration from Ubuntu to Mac OS X and it looks like ls is slightly different. For instance, it won't accept the `--color` option.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2897/clicolor-and-ls-colors-in-bash

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`ls` is actually separate from Bash. Mac OS X has a BSD version of `ls`, which requires `-G` on the command line, or `CLICOLOR` (and perhaps `LSCOLORS`) in the environment.

See `man ls` for more info.

Comment: Ditto.  I've `alias ls='ls -G'` set in my .bashrc on Snow Leopard.

Comment: For some reason, `CLICOLOR=Y` stopped working on my Mac. `alias ls='ls -G'` would force `ls` to colorize. I define this for interactive terminals only.

Answer (score 38):

Open the terminal window and type:

```
alias ls='ls -G'
```

Then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and done!

Answer (score 13):

Use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

```
brew install coreutils
```

Note that this will throw a prefix of `g` in front of all the commands (e.g., `gls` for `ls`). It gives an option to source a file that will alias these for you automatically.

I wasn't sure if there was an option to install them directly without having to do the whole alias thing, so instead in installed MacPorts and [did this](https://web.archive.org/web/20130525003910/http://brian.rarevisions.net/ubuntu-ls-colors-on-mac).

Comment: The output says: _If you really need to use these commands with their normal names, you can..._ Why does it emphasise _really_? What are the downsides?

Comment: And you never archived your page on archive.org and now your link in your last paragraph is gone

Answer (score 10):

compatibility for GNU and *BSD/darwin ls

~/.profile

```
#for *BSD/darwin
export CLICOLOR=1

ls --color=auto &> /dev/null && alias ls='ls --color=auto' ||
```

~/.bashrc (I don't remember if bash on Linux always reads ~/.profile, but not my zsh on ARCH)

```
[[ -f $HOME/.profile ]] && source $HOME/.profile
```

Comment: Can you explain this code?

Comment: setting CLICOLOR environment variable for *BSD and Darwin systems - if it's set ls and possibly other utilities would work colored, but GNU ls (for Linux) ignores it. If "ls --color=auto" will not fail (exit status =0) - we have GNU version of ls and making alias to draw color codes in interactive mode, if it fails - then we don't need alias because of CLICOLOR variable. "&> /dev/null" just don't show stderr and stdout if something fail or if it's ok. Works for my linux and osx. (p.s. bash on osx and freebsd doesn't read .bashrc, so put it in .profile. already fixed it).

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to install an alternate version of `ls`. The one usually used in linux is from the [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) project.

You could build and install or install from [macports](http://www.macports.org/), [fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) or [homebrew](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/homebrew-os-xs-missing-package-manager/).

Comment: That's overkill, in my opinion.  You don't need to install a separate version of `ls` when the same feature is supported slightly differently on the existing version of `ls`.

Comment: Good point. Then again, colored ls has never been my taste. `alias ls='ls -F'`

Comment: `alias ls='ls -FG'` -- it's the best of both worlds!

Comment: I do this using homebrew. It's not overkill if you use both Mac and *nix computers and want your terminals to look the same -- this allows you to use the same config files across all computers. It's installed as `gls` and doesn't replace the original so there's really no downside.

Answer (score 1):

I use [this Perl script I wrote on AIX](https://gist.github.com/earonesty/e04e94bbb139f6d645c6).  It’s useful if you’re on a system that doesn’t support `--color`, and also where you don’t have sudo to install packages.

Should work on Macintosh too.

Answer (score 1):

1. On Linux:

```
alias ls='ls --color'
```

2. On MacOS:

```
alias ls='ls -G'
```

Combine 2 into 1, you can input this code into .bashrc (on both Linux & MacOS).

```
myos="$(uname)"
case $myos in
Linux) alias ls='ls --color-auto';;
Darwin) alias ls=ls -G';;
*);;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Use homebrew install coreutils：

brew install coreutils

export PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"

useful link：https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/issues/966

Comment: I added that to my $PATH recently and I can't get the GNU ls to show color without explicitly doing `ls --color=auto`.. `eval $(dircolors)` set the LS_COLORS environment variable as expected but still no color without --color. ideas?

Answer (score 0):

macOS now uses `zsh` for the default terminal. To use `ls` with color output edit or create the `.zshrc` file in your home folder and add this:

```
export CLICOLOR=1
```

The other requirement is that `ls` requires a color terminal declaration, such as `xterm-16color` or `xterm-256color` in your terminal application, or it won't bother trying to do color output.